# How to serialize in a Xml several objects at this scenario?

Tags: c#, xml-serialization, linq-to-xml, xmldocument, xmlserializer

I'm having a hard time with my design in the serialization of objects.

Let my show you my scenario. I've got a general `Configuration` class and contains three properties:

```
public sealed class Configuration
{
    public Configuration(string name, Levels level, ConfigurationSpec spec)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Level = level;
        this.Spec = spec;
    }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Levels Level { get; set; }
    public ConfigurationSpec Spec { get; set; }
}
```

The last property is imporant, because it's an abstract class and it can derived from others classes:

```
public class ConfigurationSpec { }
public class BinaryConfiguration : ConfigurationSpec
{
    public Range<int> Range1 { get; set; }
    public Range<int> Range2 { get; set; }

    public BinaryConfiguration()
    {
        this.Range1 = new Range<int>();
        this.Range2 = new Range<int>();
    }

    public BinaryConfiguration(Range<int> range1, Range<int> range2)
    {
        this.Range1 = range1;
        this.Range2 = range2;
    }
}

public class Range<T> where T : IComparable<T>
{
    private T _min;
    private T _max;

    public Range()
    {
    }

    public Range(T min, T max)
    {
        this.Min = min;
        this.Max = max;
    }

    public T Min
    {
        get { return _min; }
        set { _min = value; }
    }

    public T Max
    {
        get { return _max; }
        set { _max = value; }
    }
```

All of this contain the `ConfigurationSpec` class. And the real problem is, I'm gonna add many `Specs` derived from `ConfigurationSpec`, I mean hundreds.

```
<Configuration>
    <!-- Maybe here it'll be good specify the type -->
    <ConfigurationSpec>
        <Range1 X="2" Y="4" />
        <Range2 X="5" Y="10" />
    </ConfigurationSpec>
</Configuration>
```

And I want to know how can I write and read all of this classes from a XmlFile for the serialization.

If you have any doubt, please let me know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as your `Configuration` class has a reference to the `ConfigurationSpec` it will correctly serialize/deserialize all the object they are needed.

Talking about `ConfigurationSpec` only the type referenced by the `Configuration` will be serializated(when you serialize an instance of `Configuration`).
In other word if you got 5 different `ConfigurationSpec` only the one you will pass to the `Configuration` constructor will be serializeted

Comment: If it's possible to illustrate me with a sample, please?

Comment: Another doubt, as you can see in my situation, would it be better to serialize throug XmlSerialization or XDocument from Linq

Comment: you can use XmlSerialization which is made for that